# Richfaces prevent row selection on a table

Tags: richfaces

I am a beginner in rich faces, I have an extended data table with multiple row selection.
I need to stop the user selecting rows after a limit of, say, 5 selections.
Which is the cleanest way to do so?
Thanks!